# Xamarin UserControl not loading in XAML but works in code behind

Tags: xaml, xamarin, user-controls, portable-class-library

I am trying to use a usercontrol defined outside the solution by referring the dll. It works if I use code; but not XAML

Here is the code -
1. UserControl code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Internals;

namespace ComplexControl
{
    [Preserve]
    public class ComplexControl : ContentView
    {
        public ComplexControl()
        {
            var button = new Button
            {
                Text = "Click Me!",
                //VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            };

            int clicked = 0;
            button.Clicked += (s, e) => button.Text = "Clicked: " + clicked++;

            Content = button;
        }
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false)]
        class PreserveAttribute : Attribute { }
    }
}
```

2. For the usage in the project I Reference the assembly ConplexControl in PCL

It works with code ( ie. not using XAML )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ComplexControl;

namespace CustomControlUsageExample
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            // without InitializeComponent(); works
            //this way works
            //Step 1.
            StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();
            Label lb = new Label();
            lb.Text = "Hello";
            sl.Children.Add(lb);
            sl.Children.Add(new ComplexControl.ComplexControl());
            Content = sl;
        }
    }
}
```

If I use with XAML it does not work

Like this

XAML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlUsageExample"
             x:Class="CustomControlUsageExample.MainPage"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:ComplexControl;assembly:ComplexControl">
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"/>
        <custom:ComplexControl.ComplexControl/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

And code behind for that is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using ComplexControl;

namespace CustomControlUsageExample
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            //This way does not work
            //Step 2

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried to debug thru and do not see it add the user control to content.

Can someone help me see what I am doing wrong?
It is works if I don't use XAML for the custom control.

I have a usercontrol work being done where the userControl is done using code; but it will be referred by projects inside XAML.

Thanks,

Comment: App.xaml.cs has this snippet of code. Just incase needed `public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new CustomControlUsageExample.MainPage();
        }`

Answer (score 1):

XP, you are doing everything correctly.

Unfortunately, small mistype (: instead of =) led you to this problem with XAML-defined control.

`xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:ComplexControl;assembly:ComplexControl"`

should be

`xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:ComplexControl;assembly=ComplexControl"`

Syntax for [custom XAML namespace](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces/#Declaring_Namespaces_for_Types) is `clr-namespace:NAMESPACE;assembly=ASSEMBLY`

I believe Xamarin.Forms should be smarter about namespaces and warn you about such mistypes in the editor or during build time (Xamarin.Forms does not compile XAML by default but nobody stops it from running simple syntax check, right?).

If you want, you can [file a bug to Xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug) (it is easy!)

Comment: Thanks, I step away from resolving. But the Content is showing only the Label not the button is not showing. Somehow the stack shows count of only 1 view and that is the label

Comment: Shows both for me: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dqe7b9xgcr1nor/Screenshot%202017-03-17%2011.05.39.png?dl=0 

Here is a sample solution: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8pp86n4qhl76qg/CustomControlXAML.zip?dl=0

Comment: You have Xaml creating the Content and then code behind overwrites that xaml content. What I am looking for is the ComplexControl to be embeded inside the xaml script and code behind should have only 1 statement of your example. That is InitializeComponent();

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Looking at it again. I see you are running another Xaml view. I am trying to get it to run on my system. Windows 10 VS 2015

Comment: Ping me in the chat if you need help, @XP. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138376/xamarin

Comment: I am a having bit of trouble trying to get that in Visual Studio

Comment: I was not able to initiate that chat as it needs higher reputation